Troubleshooting factoextra (R)
My dataset has 25 columns, where cols 1-24 are numeric and have missing values and 25 is categorical (two factors, 'low' or 'high').
I am trying to show a PCA like this (image taken from here on sthda.com) where my variables are labeled and my two factors (low or high) are color coated/demarcated.

First, I had to impute the missing values for my cols 1-24:
res.comp <- missMDA::imputePCA(dat[,-25],ncp=5)
Then I did PCA:
res.pca <- FactoMineR::PCA(res.comp$completeObs)
I try to graph and bring column 25 back in for groupin and get an error:
factoextra::fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, habillage = dat[,25], addEllipses =TRUE, ellipse.level = 0.68) + scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```Error in apply(ind[, colnames(grp)], 2, as.character) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length```

Does anyone have tips for how to get my graph working? TIA!

It's better if you can include a minimal reproducible example (including your data) that produces the error.
This should mimic what your doing, but with quali.sup to indicate the index of the categorical supplementary variable.
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)
library(missMDA)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  b = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  c = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  d = rep(c("low", "high"), 50)
)

df$a[1] <- NA

res.comp <- imputePCA(df, quali.sup = 4)

pca <- PCA(res.comp$completeObs, quali.sup = 4, graph = FALSE)

fviz_pca_ind(pca, habillage = 4, addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.level = 0.68) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")


Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you! I left something out in my question- is there a way to make it so that instead of the points on the graph being individuals, they are the variable attributes in vector format? I try to do this:
''''factoextra::fviz_pca_var(res.pca, habillage = 25,
addEllipses =TRUE, ellipse.level = 0.68,
gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07"))''''
But I get the error: "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

In the reprex above, fviz_pca_var(pca, col.var = "#00AFBB") should work.
